# Add timer to change image on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

So here's my code and the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dgvtvvj0/). The effects works great, only thing is I have no idea how to add a timer to it.

E.g. When someone hovers over the image, it doesn't change the image instantly. You have to keep the cursor over it for 10 seconds before it will change.

HTML

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/"><img src="chrome-extension://cipmepknanmbbaneimacddfemfbfgpgo/images/content/providers/google-translate-content.png" onmouseover="this.src='chrome-extension://cipmepknanmbbaneimacddfemfbfgpgo/images/content/providers/google-images-content.png'" onmouseout="this.src='chrome-extension://cipmepknanmbbaneimacddfemfbfgpgo/images/content/providers/google-translate-content.png'" /></a>
```

Comment: You might want to look into CSS transitions. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by setting a `timeout` in JavaScript.

```
var timer;

document.getElementById('img-hover').addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    var elem = this;
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        elem.src='chrome-extension://cipmepknanmbbaneimacddfemfbfgpgo/images/content/providers/google-images-content.png';
    }, 1000);
});

document.getElementById('img-hover').addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    var elem = this;
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        elem.src='chrome-extension://cipmepknanmbbaneimacddfemfbfgpgo/images/content/providers/google-translate-content.png';
    }, 1000);
});
```

You also need to include an ID and remove the inline click events in your HTML, so it should be this:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/"><img id="img-hover" src="chrome-extension://cipmepknanmbbaneimacddfemfbfgpgo/images/content/providers/google-translate-content.png"/></a>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TheQueue841/27jysf1p/)

Note that in the JSFiddle, I did have to change the images so I can actually see them :)

Comment: Thanks! The code works wonderful. One last thing, I'm trying to resize it via CSS and was wondering what the code was. Here's the CSS I use to resize things..........    .elem.src {
width: 215px;
}
.elem.src img {
width: 215px;
}

Comment: In the CSS, you need you to target the actual element. so instead of `.elem.src` you can just select the id with `#img-hover`. And since it's just changing the src of a single img element, you only need to set this once.

Answer (score 2):

You could use setTimeout() function from Javascript to do your thing

```
onmouseover="window.setTimeout(function(){  document.getElementById('image1').src='http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg'
},1000);"
```

Note that this.src may no longer work.

https://jsfiddle.net/BoyWithSilverWings/dgvtvvj0/3/

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/">
    <img src="chromeextension://cipmepknanmbbaneimacddfemfbfgpgo/images/content/providers/google-translate-content.png" onmouseover="setTimeout(function () { this.src='chrome-extension://cipmepknanmbbaneimacddfemfbfgpgo/images/content/providers/google-images-content.png'}, 10000)" onmouseout="this.src='chrome-extension://cipmepknanmbbaneimacddfemfbfgpgo/images/content/providers/google-translate-content.png'" />
</a>
```